# Filter rows in query based on existance of corresponding data in another table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following two tables with data.

```
test_a
+--------+-----+----------+
| j_code | amt | batch_nr |
+--------+-----+----------+
| AA_001 | 100 |        1 |           test_b
| AA_001 | 300 |        1 |           +--------+
| BB_001 | 350 |        1 |           | j_code |
| FF_001 |  50 |        1 |           +--------+
| BB_001 | 150 |        2 |           | AA_001 |
| CC_001 |  50 |        2 |           | FF_001 |
+--------+-----+----------+           +--------+
```

I'm trying to adjust the following query so that it works with the following rules:

```
select
  A.j_code
  , B.j_code
  , A.batch_nr
from test_a A
  left join test_b B ON A.j_code = B.j_code
  left join (select
              test_a.j_code
             from test_a 
               inner join test_b 
                 on test_a.j_code = test_b.j_code 
             where test_a.batch_nr = 2) code_exists 
               on code_exists.j_code = A.j_code
where A.batch_nr = 1
order by A.j_code;
```

I'm running the query on batches and for this batch (`1`) the `j_code` from test_a has a correspondent in test_b. Due to this, only the `j_code` from test_a needs to be shown.

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| A.j_code | B.j_code | batch_nr |
+----------+----------+----------+
| AA_001   | AA_001   | 1        |
| FF_001   | FF_001   | 1        |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

The problem is when I try to adjust my query for the following scenario. If I run the query for batch `2`, if there are no correspondents then I still need to show the batches from `test_a`.

```
select
  A.j_code
  , B.j_code
  , A.batch_nr
from test_a A
  left join test_b B ON A.j_code = B.j_code
  left join (select
              test_a.j_code
             from test_a 
               inner join test_b 
                 on test_a.j_code = test_b.j_code 
             where test_a.batch_nr = 2) code_exists 
               on code_exists.j_code = A.j_code
where A.batch_nr = 2
order by A.j_code;
```

Expected output:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| A.j_code | B.j_code | batch_nr |
+----------+----------+----------+
| BB_001   | NULL     | 2        |
| CC_001   | NULL     | 2        |
+----------+----------+----------+
```

I've tried different approaches with a `CASE EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause, but it didn't return the expected result.

I feel like this is very simple, but I just can't put my finger on it.

Any help is appreciated and here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ced8a/11) that can be used.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by using an analytic function to count how many j_codes are present from the B table, and then filter based on whether there were no B rows present for a given batch number, or where the B j_code is not null:

```
with test_a as (select 'AA_001' j_code, 100 amt, 1 batch_nr from dual union all
                select 'AA_001' j_code, 300 amt, 1 batch_nr from dual union all
                select 'BB_001' j_code, 350 amt, 1 batch_nr from dual union all
                select 'FF_001' j_code, 50 amt, 1 batch_nr from dual union all
                select 'BB_001' j_code, 150 amt, 2 batch_nr from dual union all
                select 'CC_001' j_code, 50 amt, 2 batch_nr from dual),
     test_b as (select 'AA_001' j_code from dual union all
                select 'FF_001' j_code from dual),
     -- end of mimicking your test_a and test_b tables
        res as (select a.j_code a_j_code,
                       b.j_code b_j_code,
                       batch_nr,
                       count(b.j_code) over (partition by batch_nr) cnt_b_j_code
                from   test_a a
                       left outer join test_b b on (a.j_code = b.j_code))
select distinct a_j_code,
                b_j_code,
                batch_nr
from   res
where  cnt_b_j_code = 0
or     b_j_code is not null
order by batch_nr, a_j_code;

A_J_CODE B_J_CODE   BATCH_NR
-------- -------- ----------
AA_001   AA_001            1
FF_001   FF_001            1
BB_001                     2
CC_001                     2
```

And here's the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ced8a/14)